# How can I find out what MVC3 is doing under the hood?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

OK, I'm an old dog (slowly) learning new tricks and I need to see the cogs turning in order to understand what's going on.

I've generated an MVC3 app using EF4.1 from an existing database and the list in the MVC3 view (based on a SQL View) shows different results to the SQL View viewed in SQL manager. Specifically, fields from a joined table seem to not get updated between multiple hits on the main table.

The funny thing is: If I capture the sql that intellisense shows for the db.myViewClass.ToList() call and paste that into SQL manager, it gives the right results!

I've also created a mini test app  and that works fine. So far I can't see how the test app differs from my main app which fails.

I'm frustrated that I can't step in to the code to see what's happening in db.myViewClass.

Any bright ideas anyone?

Dave.

Comment: how will we know what are you doing under your hood ? Show us some code please ?

Comment: Is this MVC 3 or EF 4 ? Sounds more like an issue with Entity Framework ? If you want to see what going on under the MVC 3 hood, it's open source, and can be clone off Codeplex.

Comment: The code at issue is the generated line return View(db.myclass.ToList()); In another case that bugs me I get the error message "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. " and again I'm just left guessing what caused it.